# Express $\frac{1}{(3-\sqrt{2})^2}$ in the form $p+q√2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Both $p$ and $q$ have to be rational numbers.

Anyone have a step by step solution? I have tried to expand the bracket in the denominator and then multiplied top and bottom by the conjugate but I can't get the final answer into the form p+q√2.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm still stuck on how to solve it :/

Comment: The applicable technique is often called "rationalizing the denominator".  Instead of expanding the denominator, first rationalize it (so the radicals crop up in the numerator).  Squaring things out is productive once you get to that point.

Comment: If you want more advice than "expand the bracket than multiply the top and bottom by the conjugate", then you'll have to post some more detail to explain where you're having problems carrying this out. (or at least, to show enough of your work for the reader to spot your problem)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Multiply the fraction by $\displaystyle 1 = \frac{(3+\sqrt{2})^2}{(3+\sqrt{2})^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Multiply numerator and denominator by $(3+\sqrt{2})^2$.